# How to configure NLog in a .NET Core app

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration-files, nlog

I am using a library called [DataFlowEx](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx) and it requires a configuration for NLog in order to output it's debug and other information.

The tutorial shows the configuration using xml files.

I thought of using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, and pointing that to the XML but it doesn't seem to work...

Here is what I have so far:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddXmlFile("app.config", true).Build();
```

And the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog20">
        <arg key="configType" value="FILE" />
        <arg key="configFile" value="~/NLog.config" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
</configuration>
```

And the nlog config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <variable name="logFormat" value="${date:format=yy/MM/dd HH\:mm\:ss} [${logger}].[${level}] ${message} ${exception:format=tostring} "/>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="console" layout="${logFormat}"/>
    <target xsi:type="File" name ="file" fileName="Gridsum.DataflowEx.Demo.log" layout="${logFormat}" keepFileOpen="true"/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name ="Gridsum.DataflowEx*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console,file"></logger>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Nothing is ever output... Am I doing this right?

Comment: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

Comment: @Kirk I had read that but concluded (perhaps wrongly) that it wouldn't work with the way DataFlowEx is expecting the NLog configuration to be accomplished. Am I wrong?

Comment: Enable the NLog internal debugging option (`<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">`) and look in the logs to see if there is anything there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/issues/153

Stop using the app.config, but instead use a dedicated nlog.config (Remember to configure the nlog.config-file to "Copy Always")

Comment: Using this method *exactly* causes: `Method not found: 'System.AppDomainSetup System.s.get_SetupInformation()'.`

Comment: Could you give a callstack for this exception? What version of NLog are you using?

Comment: using `Common.Logging.NLog4412` and `NLog v4.4.12`

Comment: Could you try and use the following libraries. Common.Logging ver. 3.4.1 and Common.Logging.NLog4412 and NLog v4.5-BETA07 ?

Comment: That did it! What exactly was the problem? Out of curiosity, is there an issue I can read to learn why it didn't work before? Thanks!

Comment: NLog 4.4.12 doesn't support NetStandard. This is being fixed with NLog 4.5. NetCore attempts to load full NetFramework assemblies, but will fail with Method not found if meeting a call not supported by NetStandard2.0.

Answer (score 2):

All my code for nlog looks like this in the Startup.cs.  Namely in the Configure method:

```
    using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
    using NLog.Web;
    using Nlog;

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //setup logging
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
        app.AddNLogWeb();

        // other unrelated stuff...
    }
```

For Console apps you don't need anything special...

```
using NLog;

public class Engine
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Engine()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(OutboundMessageType messageType)
    {
        _logger.Trace($"Entered SendAsync() for message type '{messageType}'.");

        // other stuff here
    }
}
```

The above is just from a random class in my project.  There is no configuration code needed.  My nlog.config resides in the same directory as the executable

Comment: Thanks but this is not an ASP.NET app, just a .NET Core app, console.

Comment: Updated from a console app I have.